# Can Entity Framework map the same column to a Navigation Property and a Foreign Key

Tags: c#, entity-framework, foreign-keys

I have a class **Car** which has a property **Type** that is a string. Type is a foreign key to the **Car Type** table but we haven't actually created that relationship in EF yet.

We have several dozen usages of Car.Type throughout our code, but now we need to access another property in the Car Type table so we need to create the relationship between the 2 objects.

So I want to go:

```cs
public class Car
{
  public string Type { get; set; }
  public CarType CarType { get; set; }
}

public class CarType
{
  public string Name { get; set; }
  public bool Display { get; set; }
}
```

```cs
builder.Property(e => e.Type).HasColumnName("type");
builder.HasOne(e => e.CarType).WithMany().HasForeignKey("type");
```

So that I can access both the navigation property and the foreign key, for example:

```cs
string typeString = myCar.Type;
bool display = myCar.CarType.Display;
```

But when I retrieve Cars, I get an SQLException saying `Invalid column name 'Type1'.`

I've tried changing this all manner of ways but I always seem to get this error. I imagine there's a way to fix it by creating a List of Cars in the CarType class, but some of the CarTypes might have tens of thousands of Cars which could make retrieving the CarTypes slow. I also don't want to eliminate the navigation property and rely solely on the foreign key property because there are dozens of things we would have to change.

Does anyone know how to do this?

Answer (score 0):

I'm flying a little blind as I can't see everything that you've done, but this is what I would do.

In the database, in the `Car` table, ensure you have a column titled `CarTypeId`.

In the database, in the `CarType` table, ensure you have the columns `Id`, `Name`, and `Display`.

`Car.CarTypeId` is a foreign key to `CarType.Id`.

Rebuild your entity diagram (edmx) by deleteing the Car and Cartype tables on the designer surface and reloading them, and the relationships should just be there.

`Type1` is likely there because you have multiple navigation properties defined (there already is a `Type`, so the tool calls the other one `Type1`. You can make this work (you could rename it), but in my experience it's a code smell and adds a manual step that you have to remember down the road. Instead of building on top of what you have, I think you should re-structure what you have correctly. After these changes, you would do this:

```
string typeString = myCar.Type;
```

would become:

```
string typeString = myCar.CarType.Name;
```

Yes, you will have to change it through your code; however, if you rebuild your entity diagram, any references to the 'old' `Car.Type` will now fail, and the application will not compile -- it should be easy to find all instances that need to be updated.

Comment: This is probably the best answer that's not the answer I'm hoping for. Unfortunately there are also a couple of constructors for Car that take in a Code, so those would have to change and then all the places that call those constructors...
This is also a legacy system and we can't change the database structure in any meaningful way.
Thanks for your help though